# Facebook Graph Api access Alcohol Related Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am looking for a solution to fetch the feeds of an alcohol-related/age-restricted Facebook Brand Page by a website or back-end service to show these infos in that website for any user.

i.e: https://graph.facebook.com/JimBeam
The standard call results with an error or false.
I know the reason is the age-restictrion because of the relation to alcohol.

If I am connected to Facebook and add an access_token (user-token or page-token) to the request, I get everything I need, but it doesn't work if I am not connected.

If I request the page-token with offline_access, it also does not work when I am not connected to Facebook.

I am a bit confused with all this token types, offline_access, permissions and so on.

Is possible to get the fb-graph-feed of an age-restricted page and load that into a website?

Answer (score 3):

To get an age-restricted feed you need to have a user access token that meets the criteria for the page. So if a user is visiting your site, they will need to authenticate your app, and then you can use the resulting access token to pull information to your website from that restricted page.

You should not be using a user's access token to display content to another user who does not meet the restrictions on the Facebook page.

An added problem is that Facebook does not expose a page's restrictions via the API, so you can't tell if a user has permission to see the page until your API request returns no data.